# sonar implementation in for java application through ant

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I am currently implementing sonar for an java appication and i have seen the below line of code is to be used but i dont understand what does it mean

```
<sonar:sonar key="org.va.vbms" version="2.8-SNAPSHOT" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
```

Is the snapshot  means we have to insert an snapshot or what?

Answer (score 0):

When uploading metrics to the Sonar database, you must indicate what version of the software is being analysed (No simple way to determine this automatically using ANT). The Sonar web page is then able to present the metrics associated with different versions of your code.

Finally, I suspect you might be running an older version of the ANT task. The version (like all other settings) is normally submitted as an ANT property:

- docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task